# How to retrieve and display files with icon on an MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, file-upload

I am looking for a suitable design sample for retrieving and displaying the attachments as a list and with icon indicating file type on a View. I displayed image files before, but I need a design sample for multiple attachments as a list. Do you have any idea such a kind of design with css? I think it will be built with list items (`<li>`, `<ul>`, etc.).

Here is the line for displaying image:

```
<img id="blah" class="photo" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Controller", new { Model.ID })" />
```

Comment: Could you do something like this? `<img src="folder/@(Model.type).jpg">`. Just have a folder full of file types and directly reference them? Or use CSS sprites and classes.

Comment: @stevenw00 Thanks for reply. Could you please post an answer containing the list definition and css classes?